# How to give a password to ubuntu user, which password recommendation does not pass?

Tags: password, system, console

When you install ubuntu you can input password for user account which even if are weak or un-recommended are allowed. But when from the command prompt if you type
`passwd`
it gives ratings on strength and does not allow the passwords to be set. Does anyone know of any force option.
`man passwd`
does not tell about any option like that.
If would like to a single digit password. How do I do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting the users password as root user i.e

```
sudo passwd user-name
```

I just tried it and set my password to "a"

```
adnan@adnan-ubuntu-vm:~$ sudo passwd adnan
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
adnan@adnan-ubuntu-vm:~$
```

Comment: Ahh, [xkcd: Sandwich](http://xkcd.com/149/) :D

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pam-auth-update --force
```

Navigate to *passwdqc password strength enforcement* and click ok to save the change.
Now you can set the password to whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the user and you want to give security code to your account then just try the following steps:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Write `passwd` on terminal.
3. Now enter the password.
4. retype the same password as above.

I hope it works for you!!
Thank you!!